# Angular 2: Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for AuthService! ; Zone: angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, service, dependency-injection

I use an AuthService and an AuthGuard to log in/log out users and guard routes. The AuthService is used in the AuthGuard as well as in a LoginComponent. The AuthGuard is used to guard routes via CanActivate. When I try to run the app I get the following error:

```
zone.js:522 Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for AuthService! ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: NoProviderError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: DI Error
    at NoProviderError.ZoneAwareError
```

I have checked that the LoginComponent and AuthGuard both import the AuthService and inject it into the components via the constructor. I have also checked that the AuthService is imported into the AppModule file and added to the providers array so it can be used as a singleton service.

**Edited to add code samples:**

My App module contains the following:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [...],
    providers: [..., AuthService, AuthGuard, ...],
    declarations: [..., LoginComponent, EntryComponent ...],
    bootstrap: [EntryComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

AuthGuard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiConfig } from '../Api';

import { AuthService } from './authservice';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private authService: AuthService,
        private router: Router,
        private config: ApiConfig
    ) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

        console.log(this.isAuthenticated());

        if (this.isAuthenticated()) {
            if (this.config.defined) {
                return true;
            } else {
                this.authService.setConfig();
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/Login']);
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Checks if user is logged in 
    isAuthenticated() {
        return this.authService.userLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

LoginComponent constructor:

```
constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private notifications: Notifications,
        private authService: AuthService
    ) {}
```

AuthService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ApiConfig } from '../Api';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(
        private http: Http,
        private router: Router,
        private config: ApiConfig
    ) {
        this.apiRoot = localStorage.getItem('apiRoot');
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code. Service classes with constructor and where and how you provide and inject them.

Comment: **AuthService** should be provided in the **AppModule** using the **providers** array, not imports.

Comment: @Mihailo sorry that was a typo on my end, meant to say providers array. It is not in the imports array. I will edit the question

Comment: @natmegs did you have this issue before implementing the **AuthGuard**?

Comment: @GunterZochbauer I've edited the question to add some code samples

Comment: @Mihailo I did not have this issue before the AuthGuard, but other aspects of the routing and project setup have also changed

Comment: What does the constructor of `AuthService` look like? Do all services have the `@Injectable()` decorator?

Comment: @GunterZochbauer Added some AuthService samples to the question. Yes, all services have @Injectable() decorator

Comment: Where do you provide `ApiConfig` and what does it's constructor look like?

Comment: @natmegs If you have **multiple modules** in you app. Are you perhaps using the AuthGuard within a separate module?

Comment: @GunterZochbauer ApiConfig is in the AppModule providers array. It has no constructor, it is just an @Injectable() export class ApiConfig { variables }

Comment: Hard to tell. If you can reproduce in Plunker or https://stackblitz.com/ I can have another look, but with the provided information I can't diagnose it.

Comment: @Mihailo Other than some 3rd party modules and the standard ones (Browser, Forms, Http, Router, etc) I have only one module

Comment: @GunterZochbauer Ok, I will try to make a minimal reproduction of the error. Thanks!

Comment: @natmegs Could you provide us with the contents of the **AuthGuards** `canActivate()` method?

Comment: @Mihailo Edited to add full AuthGuard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I didn't capitalize my AuthService import correctly in AuthGuard.....

```
import { AuthService } from './authservice';
```

should have been

```
import { AuthService } from './AuthService';
```

Note to self: imports are case sensitive

Answer (score 1):

In your app.component class @Component({}) decoration add a line that states:

`providers: [AuthService]`

This creates a singleton service for that service at that level. If you wanted to provide it at a more granular level you would provide (instantiate) it at that lower level.

Please see the first couple paragraphs in this official angular 2 [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action)

Comment: I tried this but the problem persists. I thought that injecting into NgModule's providers array would create a singleton service available in all of the components in the module?